# How to get a gps fix depending on time as well as distance?

Tags: android, location

How can I get a gps fix every 10 mins and every 200 meters?

```
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 200f, (LocationListener) this);
```

The code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your snippet doesn't show enough info, like what you do after requesting the updates.

anyway you can visit this link..
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html